# Nonsingularity of the Euclidean black hole metric

Tags: black-holes, qft-in-curved-spacetime

How can one show that the nonsingularity of the Euclidean black hole metric is required for thermal equilibrium  of the original black hole in Lorentzian signature? It is mentioned in Prof. P. K. Townstend notes in "Black Holes" (http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9707012), p38, but there's no further explanations or references.

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you are looking for but somewhat close? http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/86353/

Comment: Thank you. That's actually the argument I want to understand in more technical details.